# when using Action as a property (instead of a Field), calling the method causes error: Property access must assign to the property or use its value

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

I have StateProp()  defined as an Action Property  `Public Property StateProp() As Action`.
Calling the `StateProp()` method causes an error: **Property access must assign to the property or use its value.**
Doing the same when the Action is a Field and not a Property works fine(see first lines of sample code). **The same code in C# will work just fine, but it need it in VB...**

Below is a demonstration of the problem. It will not compile till the call to StateProp() is removed. **How can I make this work?**

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim State As Action
    State = AddressOf DoSomething1
    State()
    State = AddressOf DoSomething2
    State()

    Console.ReadLine() 'all the above works fine.

    StateProp = AddressOf DoSomething1
    'StateProp() ' **************** uncommenting this call causes compilation error: Property access must assign To the Property Or use its value.
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

'trying to use this bit fails.
Dim m_checkstate As Action
Public Property StateProp() As Action
    Get
        Return m_checkstate
    End Get
    Set
        Console.WriteLine("Changing state. Do some work")
        m_checkstate = Value

    End Set
End Property

Sub DoSomething1()
    Console.WriteLine("Something1")
End Sub

Sub DoSomething2()
    Console.WriteLine("Something2")
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: `StateProp.Invoke()`

Comment: @TnTinMn thanks. Please post it as an answer so I can flag it as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a full answer versus as opposed the terse one I gave in the comment section earlier that really did not address your problem.

Retrieving a property value is functionally equivalent to calling a Function (a method) with the same return type as the Property.  In this case, it returns an instance of `System.Action` that is a delegate. A delegate has an Invoke method that you typically call.  VB.Net allows you to use the short-hand notation `delegateName()` that is equivalent to `delegatename.Invoke()`. VB.Net also allows you to omit empty argument lists when calling methods and this is what I think has caused some of your confusion on the syntax.

For example:

```vb
Sub DoSomething()
End Sub
```

..may be called by writing this:

```vb
DoSomething
' or 
DoSomething()
```

Why are the differences between these two means of calling the method `DoSomething` relevant?  It is because for the VB.Net to understand that you want to use the short-hand notation on the Action instance returned from the Property-Get Function, you need to use the second form with the post-pended '()' followed by a second '()'.  The first set ends the method call and the second tells VB to call the Invoke method.  Please note that the argument list enclosed in '()' may not be empty if the method requires parameters.

So:

```vb
DelegateReturnedFromProperty()()
```

is equivalent to:

```vb
DelegateReturnedFromProperty.Invoke
' or
DelegateReturnedFromProperty().Invoke()
```

It is a stylistic preference, but `DelegateReturnedFromProperty()()` just seems to be asking for confusion if the code is reviewed by someone that is not fully versed on VB.Net's syntactic sugar for invoking a delegate.